# How to see my domain name in URL with Google appEngine

Tags: domains, url, google-app-engine

I have a domain name : somewhere.com
this domain is mapped to somewhere.appspot.com
the Google hosting service.

Everything works well
BUT
When the users want to click on a link, they see the link as
somewhere.appspot.com/somepage.php
they get the right page but I would like them to see:
somewhere.com/somepage.php

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just mapped your domain to your appspot site. You have to set up appspot if you want to use a custom domain.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML base tag in your webpage to make all the relative links point to somewhere.com instead of somewhere.appspot.com.

```
<base href="http://somewhere.com/">
```

You can also use the below PHP code to redirect the user to somewhere.com

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(!startsWith($host, 'somewhere.appspot.com')){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://somewhere.com".$request_uri); 
}

function startsWith($haystack,$needle,$case=true) {
    if($case){return (strcmp(substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)),$needle)===0);}
    return (strcasecmp(substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)),$needle)===0);
}
```